# Roll backup plan for WSP solution deployments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, solution-package, solution-deployment

What should be the ideal roll back plan for WSP (Farm) Solutions deployments?
What backups should be taken? Before taking the backups what are the prerequisites that should be performed like, databases to static, stopping timer jobs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For roll back or complete uninstall you have to do 3 things.

1. Deactivate the features on site collections.
2. Retract / Uninstall the Solutions. You can do it via central admin or powershell.
3. Remove the solutions from farm. you can do it via power-shell or central admin.

   Disable-SPFeature -identity "MyCustom" -URL http://somesite

   Uninstall-SPSolution –Identity Solution.wsp –WebApplication http://webapplicatio

   Remove-SPSolution –Identity Solution.wsp

Useful link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543958(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: What if it has to be a DR effort for failure of deploying solutions.

Comment: If deployment failed, right? In that case same steps followed

Comment: Ok, we tried to deploy new solution, be retracted, removed old solutions and tried to deploy new solutions. It failed to deploy. We tried deploying old solutions but those failed as well. Since we are approaching the downtime window, we just restored the VM backups. What could be the ideal thing to plan for such situations? What backups we should take? During the backups, does the Farm should go read only mode to make sure that no production data is lost?

Comment: what the error you are facing? i think solution not retracted properly. You may need to recycle timer service, Admin service as well as reset IIS on servers. Also check from central admin if it is still displaying anything related to removed solution?

Comment: When we deployed the solution, from central admin it shows the wsp is deployed, but when we check in the 15 hive folder, the latest files are not visible on all the servers in the farm. When we tried to access the site, we got a correlation id - which says the files were missing. Hence we tried to redeploy the old WSP`s, and the same problem occurred. So what should we do in such cases? how should be our roll back plan.

Comment: did you recycle the timer job on all servers? also when u removed the solution, did it removed the files from 15 hive as well?

Comment: I believe it removed, because when we tried to access the site locally only on one server(App server CM hosted) it loaded but it didnt load via WFEs.

Comment: We have seen the issues where old files are being loaded by sharepoint. in our case recycling the TimerServices and Admin service fix the issue. I would remove the solution then make sure, Central admin say its removed, Check hive folder and make sure files gone from there. recycle the Timer job so it offload the dlls.

Answer (score 1):

For a WSP rollback, you would simply disable the Features deployed by the WSP (be they farm, Web App, Site, or Web), then retract the WSP. You don't need to do anything with databases nor timer jobs.

Comment: Ok, we tried to deploy new solution, be retracted, removed old solutions and tried to deploy new solutions. It failed to deploy. We tried deploying old solutions but those failed as well. Since we are approaching the downtime window, we just restored the VM backups. What could be the ideal thing to plan for such situations? What backups we should take? During the backups, does the Farm should go read only mode to make sure that no production data is lost?

Comment: You need to look at your solutions; perhaps there is an issue with the retraction. Perhaps you need to recycle the timer service (e.g. you're implementing a timer job), etc. Also, online VM backups for SharePoint are not supported.

Comment: When we deployed the solution, from central admin it shows the wsp is deployed, but when we check in the 15 hive folder, the latest files are not visible on all the servers in the farm. When we tried to access the site, we got a correlation id - which says the files were missing. Hence we tried to redeploy the old WSP`s, and the same problem occurred. So what should we do in such cases? how should be our roll back plan.